# DTC status byte - DEM AUTOSAR

Tags: diagnostics, autosar, non-volatile

I know I should save DTCs and snapshot data to non-volatile memory in case of failure, but should I also save DTC status bits?

I think these bytes have instantaneous changing bits.

For example, while the tester was testing the system, an error occurred and the DTC was recorded, at that moment the status of the testFailed bit will change and will be able to report it, right?

I have another question about the DTC Status bytes,

Do I need to use these bytes when reading DTCs from memory?

I've seen its use with DTCStatusMask, but I don't understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the DTC bits will be changed immediately as soon as you report the fault status.

For example, Bit3(Confirmed DTC bit) will be set when the threshold limit of Dem cycles count is reached with fault status as Failed continuously. In the same way, it will be cleared only when the threshold limit of Dem cycles count (Aging limit) is reached with fault status as passed continuously.

Similarly, Bit2(Pending DTC bit) will be cleared in the next ignition cycle only though it is set immediately along with Bit0(Test Failed bit).

No only these 2 bits, remaining other bits also required to be saved into NvM to report correct information about the DTC.

So, DTCs/Events status byte need to be saved into NvM to process certain information.